# ACF repeater showing just 1 row

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, advanced-custom-fields

So when I try to use ACF repeater field instead of showing me all the fields I get just the first one. The code is as follows.

```
<?php if( have_rows('vsi_projekti') ): ?>
    <ul class="posts-grid">                 
        <?php while( have_rows('vsi_projekti') ): the_row();
            // vars
            $image = get_sub_field('vsi_projekti_image');
            $content = get_sub_field('project_name');
            $link = get_sub_field('link_to_post');
            ?>  
            <li class="post-grid">
                <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt'] ?>" />
                    <div class="post-title-hover"><?php echo $content; ?></div>
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Any advice on what I'm doing wrong to be getting out just 1 row instead of multiple?
I don't know if this has anything to do with my problem or not, but I'm adding just 1 row in every post. But in the end I should get out more then just row I think?

Comment: Did you tried debugging the code by using something like `var_dump(have_rows('vsi_projekti'))`? Maybe the `have_rows()` is only returning one result.

Comment: If I try var_dump I get out bool(true) that's it.

Comment: If I try var_dump I get out bool(true) that's it. Which is at it should be, if I do var_dump('vsi_projekti') I get out string(12) which should be correct, I have 12 elements in this ACF atm.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, didn't read it's ACF. I would try the Basic PHP foreach loop listed in the [ACF repeater documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/). The `$rows` may be easier to debug with var_dump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are confused what a ACF repeater field does. If you enter just one row in every post witrh a repeater, it's normal that you get only one row... because your code works perfectly fine ... for a repeater within a post... when you add 15 rowds in your post you will get all 15rows as output...

But if you want to output every row of every repeater of every post, yopur code doesn't work. You should try this instead:

```
    <?php

  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
  );

  $posts = get_posts($args);

  if( $posts ): ?>
    <ul class="posts-grid"> 
    <?php foreach( $posts as $post ): setup_postdata( $post ); ?>

      <?php if( have_rows('vsi_projekti') ): ?>

          <?php while( have_rows('vsi_projekti') ): the_row();
              // vars
              $image = get_sub_field('vsi_projekti_image');
              $content = get_sub_field('project_name');
              $link = get_sub_field('link_to_post');
              ?>  
              <li class="post-grid">
                  <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>">
                      <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt'] ?>" />
                      <div class="post-title-hover"><?php echo $content; ?></div>
                  </a>
              </li>
          <?php endwhile; ?>

      <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endforeach; //foreach( $posts as $post ) ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </ul>
  <?php endif; // if( $posts )  ?>
```

This code gets all posts and loops throug them... In every loop the repeater field is put out....